# Getting a Foursquare consumer key error in Android

Tags: android, oauth, foursquare

I am trying to integrate foursquare into my android app.I followed the native Oauth steps from their github link https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth/blob/master/README.md#setting-up-your-app

But when I try to get the resultcode, it says that the value (client id) is invalid for consumer key attached screenshot. is it a keystore mismatch? But I checked even that.

[image]

Comment: you have not cretaed ur id correctly

Comment: @rashi. I entered my app name. the download and home page I have not given the right values as its android app and I dont have a download page and url right now. last I entered the Android Key Hashes. debug key hash to be precise.Anything else to be done?

Comment: ya that doesnt matter..follow this link ...https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: it will perfectly help you..i also faced teh same problem

Comment: and then see this https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth

Comment: @rashi. What should I give for callback url?I do not ahve any server setup.

Comment: for that just put www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window ->preferences->Android->Build
You will find MD5 fingerprint & SHA1 fingerprint 
Take them, copy and paste them in the Android Key Hashes in Foursquare site and separate between them with (,)
And test